# Zeta Infinite Summation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\,\zeta(s+n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, zeta-functions

Let $Re\{s\}\gt0$ :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right) n^{-(s+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) n^{-(s+1)} = \zeta(s+1) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+1)}}{n+1} = \\[6mm]
\zeta(s+1) - \zeta(s+2) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+2)}}{n+1} = \zeta(s+1) - \zeta(s+2) + \zeta(s+3) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+3)}}{n+1} = \text{...} \Rightarrow \\[6mm]
\sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n-1} \zeta(s+n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} - (-1)^{N}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1} \Rightarrow \\[6mm]
\boxed{ \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \zeta(s+n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} - \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[(-1)^{N}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1}\right] \quad } \\[6mm]
$$

> Does the limit exist? and What does it equal?
>   $$ L = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[(-1)^{N}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1}\right] \qquad\qquad\colon\space Re\{s\} \gt 0 \tag{1}$$
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \zeta(s+n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} - L \qquad\colon\space Re\{s\} \gt 0 \tag{2}$$

Without the outer sign, the limit is:
$$
\small \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n^2}\lt\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1}\lt\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n} \Rightarrow \zeta(s+N+2)-1 \lt \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1} \lt \zeta(s+N+1)-1 \\
\small \text{Let}\space\left\{N\rightarrow\infty\right\}\space\text{and use the limit}\space\left\{\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(z)=1\right\} \Rightarrow \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1}=0 \Rightarrow \color{red}{\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}} \\
$$
NB: appreciating your explanations on a similar [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992327/zeta-infinite-summation-sum-n-0-infty-1n-a-n-zetasn). Many Thanks.

---

### conclusion:

As of the correct answer(s):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\,\zeta(s+n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\color{red}{\zeta(s+2n-1)-\zeta(s+2n)}\right] \\[6mm]
\quad = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-(s+N)}}{n+1} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} \quad\colon\space Re\{s\}\ge0 \quad\{\small\text{holds for s=0 too}\normalsize\} \\[6mm]
$$

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\zeta(s+n)$$ is not a convergent series in the usual sense, since $\zeta(s+n)\approx 1$ for large values of $n$ (or $s$, or both) and $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}$ is not convergent in the usual sense. Are you considering such series "à la Cesàro"?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Yes indeed! We are on the same page. Thank you. Any possibility to apply  average Cesàro in this case?

Comment: In such a case, by the integral representation of the $\zeta$ function, $$\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}\zeta(s+n) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{x^m}{(s+m)!}\right)\frac{x^s \,dx}{e^x-1}.$$

Comment: Grouping the terms by two $$\sum_{n \ge 1} \zeta(s+2n-1)-\zeta(s+2n)$$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the geometric series, for $Re(s) > 0$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1} = \frac12+\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-s-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty n^{-k}(-1)^k = \frac12+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-s-1} n^{-k}(-1)^k$$
$$ = \frac12+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (\zeta(s+k+1)-1)= \frac12+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\zeta(s+2k-1)-\zeta(s+2k))$$
where the change of order of summation is allowed because $\sum_{n=2}^\infty |n^{-s-1}|\sum_{k=0}^\infty n^{-k}= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^{-Re(s)-1}}{1-\frac1n}$ so it converges absolutely

Comment: Re-writing alternating terms as subtracting of odd and even indexes terms is a key to change divergent series to absolute convergent. Thanks. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

$$(-1)^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{-s+N}}{n+1}=\begin{cases}\ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{-s+N}}{n+1}\\-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{-s+N}}{n+1}\end{cases}$$

For the limit to exist, the positive limit must equal the negativet limit, and thus we get that $L$ must be $0$ if it exists.  It is trivial to show that the limit cannot be zero.

Comment: Would you mind to demonstrate how L cannot be zero?

Comment: @HazemOrabi Add the first few terms.  Where is it going?

Comment: Because of the outer sign, we are facing a bit difficulties with the first term! not to mention few terms after.

Comment: @HazemOrabi Which is why my answer splits the cases so we may ignore the outer sign.  Now, what are the first few terms of the sum when the outer sign is positive?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, But if we consider Jack’s comments regarding $\zeta(s+n)\approx 1$ and the last value of the limit without the outer sign, then the limit may exist  (not in the usual sense), and may equal $\log(2)/2$ or $1/4$. Nevertheless, I have to admit, it may not exist.

Comment: @HazemOrabi It clearly does not exist in the usual sense, since it fails the term test.  Also, pretty much all sums exist outside of the usual sense, though I'm not sure why you'd bring that in.

Comment: @HazemOrabi Also, I don't think you Cesàro summed that correctly, since it should be dependent on $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$S(N)
=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{n^{-s}}{n+1}
=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s(n+1)}
$.

If $Re(s)> 0$,
$\lim_{N \to \infty} S(N)$
exists by comparison with
$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{1+Re(s)}}
$.

Then,
since
$\frac1{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k x^k
-\frac{x^{2m+1}}{1+x}
$

$\begin{array}\\
S(N)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{s+1}(1+1/n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{s+1}}(\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k n^{-k}
-\frac{n^{-2m-1}}{1+1/n})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k n^{-k}
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\frac{n^{-2m-1}}{1+1/n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k \frac1{n^{k+s+1}}
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(1+1/n)n^{s+2m+2}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2m}\sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^k \frac1{n^{k+s+1}}
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{s+2m+1}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k\sum_{n=1}^{N}  \frac1{n^{k+s+1}}
-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{s+2m+1}}\\
&= S_1(N)-S_2(N)\\
\end{array}
$

As $N \to \infty$,
$S_1(N)
= \sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k\sum_{n=1}^{N}  \frac1{n^{k+s+1}}
\to \sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k \zeta(k+s+1)
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
S_2(N)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{s+2m+1}}\\
&\gt \frac12\\
\text{and}\\
S_2(N)
&=\frac12+\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{s+2m+1}}\\
&\le\frac12+\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{2m}n^{s+1}}\\
&=\frac12+\frac1{4^m}\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{s+1}}\\
&\lt\frac12+\frac1{4^m}\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{(n+1)n}\\
&=\frac12+\frac1{4^m}\sum_{n=2}^{N} (\frac1{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\\
&<\frac12+\frac1{2\cdot 4^m}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\lim_{m \to \infty} S_2(N)
= \frac12
$,
so that
$\lim_{m \to \infty, N \to \infty} S(N)
=-\frac12+\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k \zeta(k+s+1)
$.

Note that,
if we write
$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k \zeta(k+s+1)
=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(\zeta(2k+s+1)-\zeta(2k+s+2))
+\zeta(2m+s+1)
$,
the sum converges properly.
If we do this grouping
earlier on
(even and odd terms together
with opposite signs),
this all becomes rigorous.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer. I allowed myself to choose a second correct answer. Please accept my apology. Meanwhile, may I ask your help in the (similar previous question) mentioned above. Appreciating. Hazem.